# Dask element wise string concatination

Tags: python, numpy, dask

I need to create a multi-index for dask by concatenating two arrays (preferably dask arrays). I found the following solution for numpy, but looking for a dask solution

```
cols=100000
index = np.array([x1 + x2 +x3 for x1,x2,x3 in zip(repeat(1,cols ).astype('str'),repeat('-',cols ),repeat(1,cols ).astype('str'))])
```

if I pass it da.from_array() it balks at + two arrays.

I have also tried np.core.defchararray.add(), this works but converts to dask array to numpy arrays (as far as i can tell).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [da.map_blocks](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.core.map_blocks).  You can make a numpy function that does whatever you want, and then `da.map_blocks` will apply that numpy function blockwise on to each of the numpy arrays that make up your dask array.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Sure, there are several in the [map blocks docstring](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.core.map_blocks) in the docs